# How to put the TextView at the Center?

Tags: android, android-layout

The following is the code of `main.xml`, which i have used to create a row adapter for JSON

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="4dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.88"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="pumpName"
        android:id="@+id/tvPump" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Time"
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/yes" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The above code produces no error but the Time `TextView` does not come at the center.

I have tried `android:gravity="center"` but it did not work.

[This is the image of my android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObPNe.png)

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` with `layout_centerInParent` attribute set to true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center a textview inside a linearlayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474982/how-to-center-a-textview-inside-a-linearlayout)

Answer (score 1):

Relative Layout could come in handy here like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPump"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="pumpName"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/yes" />

</RelativeLayout>
```