# Adjust TextView to Vertically center in LinearLayout (horizental)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, center, layout-gravity

I have four `TextView` in `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"`. Below in image, I want my fourth `TextView` to `vertically center` with respect to other views, In simple words, I want to move my fourth `TextView` a little bit up so it looks like in the center. I tried to add layout:gravity and margins but its not working.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tv_amenities"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_main_feature_LL"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rating_background"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_food_and_restaurant"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Resturant"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rating_background"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_tv_black_24dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="LCD Tv"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rating_background"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_local_parking_black_24dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Parking"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_plus_amenities"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_background"
            android:text="+15"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do that by adding `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` and removing your margin bottom.

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_plus_amenities"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/round_background"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this prop to your `@+id/tv_amenities` LinearLayout

> android:gravity="center_vertical"

Answer (score 1):

Use **android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"** attribute in your TextView's

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code inside a constraint layout and it's fine.
All I changed is in your last TextView:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Or

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

> The layout_gravity=center looks the same as
>   layout_gravity=center_horizontal here because they are in a vertical
>   linear layout. You can't center vertically in this case, so
>   layout_gravity=center only centers horizontally.

This [link can help you to fix your issue in LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474982/how-to-center-a-textview-inside-a-linearlayout)

You might find this link useful:[What is the difference between gravity and layout_gravity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482742/what-is-the-difference-between-gravity-and-layout-gravity-in-android)

Comment: I am using this under RelativeLayout but you tried it in ConstrainLayout. Moreover, already tried `android:layout_gravity="center"` but it's not working fine.

Comment: It shouldn't be a big difference (in code) between Relative and Constraint Layout.
I created a little code snippet on  [GitHub.](https://gist.github.com/LaszloLajosT/43b816ed420da4355264a1ad1835d86b)  I hope it helps.